# How to disable flyway in a particular Spring profile?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, flyway, spring-profiles

Now I have a spring-boot app which uses MsSQL server. And we use flyway for migrations.

I want to add an additional profile for tests. I want to generate tables from entity classes instead of using flyway.

I tried smth to write like this in application.yaml

```
spring:
  profiles: test
  jpa:
      generate-ddl: true
      hibernate:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:test_db;MODE=MSSQLServer
    username: sa
    password:
```

but flyway starts anyway

Answer (score 76, accepted):

**Doesn't for for Spring Boot 2.X !** Correct answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47837303/979772).

Continue reading if you need an answer for Spring Boot 1.X.

There is a property available for spring-boot to disable flyway if it's needed `flyway.enabled` which is true by default.

You can have a profile specific configuration, in your case it should be named as `application-test.yml`. This configuration can disable flyway if profile is active. You just have to declare it as follows:

```
flyway:
  enabled: false
```

And if you specify test profile in common configuration, just add it to it's root.

Comment: If you just need the flyway not to swear that some migrations are not applied, you can use spring.flyway.out-of-order = true

Answer (score 205):

FYI, for anybody who comes here looking for this, [the property name has changed for Spring Boot 2.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#flyway):

For `application.properties` format:

```
spring.flyway.enabled=false
```

For `application.yml` format:

```
spring:
    flyway:
        enabled: false
```

**Update:** To disable flyway in a specific profile, you can put that property in the properties file specific to that profile. For instance, if your profile is called "abc", you can put it in `application-abc.properties`. Check out [Spring's documentation on Profile-specific properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties) for more clarity on how to name the files. Generally, the format is `application-{profileName}.properties`.

Comment: this doesn't go under spring. 
flyway:
   enabled: false

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow your comment.

Comment: @gstackoverflow See update, I added some commentary and a link on how to apply properties to specific profiles.

Comment: Glad it helped @gstackoverflow

Comment: alternatively, the following is perfectly valid in `application.yml`: `spring.flyway.enabled: false`. If it does not work, try putting 'false' in quotes...

Answer (score 8):

JIC the official documentation with current spring boot 2.x :
[Data migration properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#data-migration-properties) and take a look on tag **# FLYWAY** you will find many properties that can help you.

```
spring.flyway.enabled=false # Whether to enable flyway.
```

Answer (score 0):

I am having multiple profiles e.g.

1. application-integration.yml
2. application.yml

in application.yml

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: ${ENVIRONMENT_NAME:local}
  flyway:
    enabled: true
    user: ${ORACLE_DB_USER:#{null}}
    password: ${ORACLE_DB_PASS:#{null}}
    locations: classpath:db/migration
    url: ${DB_URL:#{null}}
    driver-class-name: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    #    skipExecutingMigrations: true
    tablespace: MY_TABLESPACE_NAME
    baselineOnMigrate: true
    schemas: MY_SCHEMA_NAME
```

in application-integration.yml

```
spring:
  flyway:
    enabled: false
```

when I am running it, its not disabling flyway migration. I am using SpringBoot2.3.4

Answer (score -1):

Here eample of `application.yaml` It defines 2 profiles:
  1. `enable_flyway_profile` - enables flyway
  2. `disable_flyway_profile` - disables flyway

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: "enable_flyway_profile"
  flyway:
    enable: true
  ....

---

spring:
  profiles:
    active: "disable_flyway_profile"
  flyway:
    enable: false
  ....
```

Comment: not really. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html what you are looking for is `spring.profiles: "enable_flyway_profile"` the `active` property is to define which profile is active

Comment: @TecHunter it might be surprise for you but that code works in production sucessfully

Comment: oh okay, good to know! i prefer the way you wrote it too :) more explicit